# Downloaded dynamic wallpapers glitch

Tags: wallpaper

As seen in the image below, I have downloaded 3 custom dynamic wallpapers from [this website](https://dynamicwallpaper.club). All three default to the "night" wallpaper, and the drop-down menu to change it to dynamic is glitched. The text is overlapping, and clicking on it gives the image stretching/fitting options.

I am on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1.

[image: Desktop & Screen Saver (System Preferences)]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to put them in "the right" folder to make them work properly.

You can find all different rather complicated solutions including disabling the SIP (System Integrity Protection) with going into the Safe Mode and so on, but the easiest method that works (as of Big Sur 11.2.1) is to copy them to: `/Library/Desktop Pictures` folder for which you need only regular root rights:

So basically you do something like:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/Firewatch.heic /Library/Desktop\ Pictures
```

then you see them appear along with the original ones:

[image]

Comment: I did try this. I get an error saying `cp: /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Lakeside.heic: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Did you do: `sudo cp Pictures/Lakeside.heic /Library/Desktop\ Pictures` ?

Comment: Yep, even with `sudo`, it doesn't work

Comment: @AamodPant Are you sure about the paths? Because in you first comment they are totally wrong. Can you paste them here?

Comment: The path suggested by you in your comment does not exist for me. The path I have used, I got using this method: 

In the "Desktop & Screen Saver" window, double-click "Desktop Pictures" folder name in the left column. This will open it in a Finder Window. In the new Finder window, right click the "desktop pictures" directory with the option button pressed down, and select "Copy Desktop Pictures as Pathname". This gives the following path- `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`

Comment: @AamodPant That's true, but this folder is protected by SIP. Instead try to use folder `/Library/Desktop\ Pictures` if you don't have one already, then try create one and put your wallpaper there. It works for the latest Big Sur and Catalina (10.15.7)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error as before with this command as well